# stored procedure for importing txt in sql server db

Tags: c#, sql-server, import, text-files

I have to insert new records in a database every day from a text file ( tab delimited).
I'm trying to make this into a stored procedure with a parameter for the file to read data from.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UpdateTable

    @FilePath

    BULK INSERT TMP_UPTable 
    FROM @FilePath
    WITH 
    ( 
        FIRSTROW = 2, 
        MAXERRORS = 0, 
        FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t', 
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' 
    )

    RETURN
```

Then i would call this stored procedure from my code (C#) specifying the file to insert.

This is obviously not working, so how can i do it ?

Just to be clear the problem here is that i can't pass the parameter `@FilePath` to the `FROM` clause, or at least i don't know how.

Comment: Why you need it to do that way. May be you can use SSIS, BulkCopy or BCP at least...

Comment: because the db will be update by multiple users who don't have sql server access, they will just provide a txt file and the app will insert that into the db. ( into a temp table first, do some checks and finally append to another table)

Comment: Ok, but I see no problem to load that files using SSIS. Somehow those files will be passed to some directory. I mean you can load that files from there. If this is not the case please provide more details.

Comment: SSIS can be scheduled to run regularly and check a directory, or can even get files from an email account.  Lots of options.

Comment: the database is on a sql server where i have no control, i just store my db there. and now i only have an express edition so no ssis.

Comment: No worries you still can use bcp.exe it will be much more faster then calling SP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I misunderstood.
You need to create the SQL statement dynamically and then execute it:

```
    CREATE procedure dbo.UpdateTable

    @FilePath varchar(max)
AS

 declare @sql varchar(max)
 declare @parameters varchar(100)
 set @parameters = 'FIRSTROW = 2, MAXERRORS = 0, FIELDTERMINATOR = ''\\t'', ROWTERMINATOR = ''\\n'' '
 SET @SQL = 'BULK INSERT TMP_UPTable FROM ' + @FilePath + @parameters

EXEC (@SQL)

RETURN
```

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for.
i think i have some other kind of problem now : 
"The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 1. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly."

Comment: Maybe some adjustment of the "set @parameters =..."  is needed.

Comment: i am looking at my text file - the data is delimited by tabs (Hex $9) but at the end of the line i have the same thing.
Maybe the delimiters are not escaped properly, i've tried ''\t'' and i get the same error

Comment: the problem is definitively in the txt file, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I am late here, but I would suggest a different approach - open the file in your C# application and convert it to something more SQL-friendly, a DataTable or even XML. In C# you have complete control over how you parse the files. Then write the stored procedure to accept your DataTable or XML. A DataTable is preferable, but cannot be used with Entity Framework.

There is lots of help around of how to do inserts by joining to this sort of input, and SQL Server is optimised for set operations.